# Update a Listbox with a new array when selecting a checkbox

Tags: autohotkey

I have a listbox, it displays files in my downloads folder. But I also have a filter checkbox that will refine results only to .zip extension if I choose it. So it essentially needs to clear/reset/refresh the array to be only .ZIP if I check the box. But it's erroring telling me `the same variable cannot be used for more than 1 control.` But I'm not using it twice. So my strategy must be incorrect.

[image]

```
Gui, Add, Text, x15 y+50, Downloads Folder | Extension Filters:
Gui, Add, Checkbox, x+20 vFileType gFileFilter1, ZIP    ;Checkbox for filetype filter
Gui, Font, cBlack s9
FileFilter1:
Gui, Add, ListBox, x15 vMyListBox gMyListBox w240 r5
Gui, Add, Button, Default, OK


Gui, submit, nohide 
Downloads:= "C:\Users\me\Downloads\"
if (FileType=1)
  {
    download_filters:= "*.ZIP"
  }
else
  {
    download_filters:= "*.*"
  }
msgbox % Downloads download_filters
; Loops files, applies a sort, sticks results in gui listbox.
FileList := 
Loop files, % Downloads download_filters
  {
    FileList .= A_LoopFileTimeModified "," A_LoopFileName . "|"
  }
Sort, FileList, R D|  ; Sort, reverse order. Use '|' as the Delimiter.
NewFileList .= RegExReplace(FileList,"[0-9]{14},","")
GuiControl,, MyListBox, %NewFileList%

Gui, Show, w525 h500, AHK Super GUI
return

MyListBox:
if (A_GuiEvent != "DoubleClick")
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time I call 'FileFilter1:' its trying to add another 'ListBox' control rather than modifying the original one; move the gui stuff outside the label to avoid this. Second; to update a listbox (instead of adding to the array) you need to lead with `"|" VariableName` so the entire line to update the listbox would be: `GuiControl ,,MyList,% "|" NewList`

```
Gui Add,Text,x15 y+50,Downloads Folder | Extension Filters:
Gui Add,Checkbox,x+20 vFileType gFileFilterSub,ZIP
Gui Font,cBlack s9
Gui Add,ListBox,x15 vMyList gMyListBox w240 r5
Gui Add,Button,Default,OK
Gui Submit,NoHide

Downloads:="C:\Users\" A_UserName "\Downloads\"

FileFilterSub:
  Gui Submit,NoHide      ;'Submit' to get the checkbox value first
  If (FileType=1)
    FileFilter:="*.ZIP"
  Else
    FileFilter:="*.*"
  FileList:=""
  Loop Files,% Downloads FileFilter
    FileList.=A_LoopFileTimeModified "," A_LoopFileName "|"
  Sort FileList,R D|
  NewList:=RegExReplace(FileList,"[0-9]{14},","")
  GuiControl ,,MyList,% "|" NewList  ;Start with '|' to overwrite!
  Gui Show,w525 h500,AHK Super GUI
Return

MyListBox:
  If (A_GuiEvent!="DoubleClick")
Return
```